# Multiple Render Targets in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Is multiple render targets supported in Three.js? I mean, using one single fragment shader to write to different render targets.

I have a fragment shader that calculates several things and I need to output them separately into different textures for further manipulations.

Comment: I guess you need to provide some code so people can help you out.

Comment: It's more of a conceptual yes/no question, so I didn't include any source codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple render targets are not supported in three.js.

If you are interested in GPGPU within the framework of three.js, you can find a nice example here: http://jabtunes.com/labs/3d/gpuflocking/webgl_gpgpu_flocking3.html. Just be aware, it is using an older version of three.js.

three.js r.60

Comment: They are now supported: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/16390

Answer (score 1):

Though the above answer was correct at the time of its writing, it is no longer the case.

With the introduction of WebGL2, ThreeJS does indeed support multiple render targets.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLMultipleRenderTargets